# PHP/MYSQL - Insert into ignore, and ignore a specified column

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I need to be able to only insert a row if the data doesn't already exist, except for the date column, which would always be different, so it will always insert a new row even though it shouldn't.

my code:

```
$postID = $_POST['postID']; //example, 817
$userID = logged_in(); //example, 2
$date = time();

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO likes SET userID='$userID', postID='$postID', date='$date'");
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE date INTO likes SET userID='$userID', postID='$postID', date='$date'");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `userID` and `postID` you can do whatever you're doing now, the date column would not get updated if there's already a record.

If you want to have the date column updated if the record does exist (for that particular user and post) you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date = '$date'`.

Comment: I would suggest you check the docs and also make sure you don't already have existing indexes, but this should do it: `ALTER TABLE LIKES ADD UNIQUE(userID, postID);`

Comment: Ohh, now I understand what you meant by the unique constraints, I never even thought about doing it this way, thanks. I'll have to be using this more often.